# What is the python equivalent of 'var myNumber = dictionary['myNumber'] || 3

Tags: javascript, python

In javascript, we can use the || operator to set a variable since it stops at the first expression which results to a truthy value.
What is the equivalent of the following in python?

```
var myNumber = dictionary['myNumber'] || 3
```

Comment: This works in python as well, just drop the `var`. It's not idomatic, however.

Comment: Is this a python 3 thing? In python 2.7.2, I get a syntax error

Comment: @1dayitwillmake The accepted answer won't work if `dictionary['myNumber']` returns a Falsy value, so it is not equivalent to your js code.

Comment: @1dayitwillmake I am not whining, if `dictionary['myNumber'] = False`, then in python `dictionary.get('myNumber', 3)` would return `False` not 3. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with

```
myNumber = dictionary.get('myNumber', 3)
```

If you wanted only a truthy value or 3, then you would do it like this:

```
myNumber = dictionary.get('myNumber') or 3
```

Comment: That's different though, that only returns 3 if `myNumber` doesn't exist in the dictionary

Comment: tbh... it's hard to tell, javascript just has a slightly more loose syntax in this regard.

Comment: After your edit, the `False` is not needed. By default it will return `None` which also evaluates to `False`

Comment: Actually, checking if it exist in the dictionary is how I plan to use the syntax - not checking for false, just taking advantage of how javascript handles the situation as sberry correctly inferred

Comment: This is not same as the js version, if `dictionary['myNumber']` returns a Falsy value then it going to assign that value to `myNumber`, But the js code will assign 3.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: right you are, and I had updated my answer as such, but it turns out the OP was looking for the functionality that `get()` provides.

Answer (score 2):

```
myNumber = dictionary['myNumber'] if dictionary['myNumber'] else 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as easy, just use `or` instead of `||`

```
myNumber = dictionary['myNumber'] or 3
```

Comment: `myNumber = dictionary.get('myNumber') or 3` will also work in the case that the key is missing

Comment: @gnibbler: indeed, but that was already posted by sberry so obsolete to add :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict.get` and use `or` instead of `||`:

Python:

```
>>> dic = {'a':1, 'b': False}
>>> dic.get('a') or 3
1
>>> dic.get('b') or 3           #Key with falsy value
3
>>> dic.get('c') or 3           #missing key
3
```

Js:

```
> dic = {'a':1, 'b': false}
> dic['a'] || 3
1
> dic['b'] || 3
3
> dic['4'] || 3
3
```

Note that the set of values defined as `Falsy` in python and js can vary so the answer can different for cases.

Comment: @1dayitwillmake fixed. I wasn't aware of fact that js returns undefined for missing keys. :)

Comment: @downvoter care to explain your downvote, so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Same idea, different syntax:

```
myNumber = dictionary.get('myNumber') or 3
```

`.get()` returns `None` (non-truthy) for non-existent keys, or the value itself if the key exists, just like javascript's `[]`. `or` evaluates to the first truthy value it comes across, just like javascript's `||`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to catch the error raised by the value not existing, like so:

```
try:
    myNumber = dictionary['myNumber']
except KeyError:
    myNumber = 3
```

you could then build this into a function:

```
def dictAssign(dictionary,attempt,fail):
    try:
        return dictionary[attempt]
    except KeyError:
        return fail
```

and then you can use this by calling the function:

```
myNumber = dictAssign(dictionary,"myNumber",3)
```

Comment: didn't see his post before writing, maybe this will help OP on his learning anyway!

Comment: using try..except as flow control is generally ill-advised.